# [solved] rosrun beginner_tutorials talker.py has no effect

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I apply the WritingPublisherSubscriber(python) tutorial page.

I copy/paste the code of talker.py (error on wget)

I execute

`$ catkin_make`

roscore is runing

Then I execute

`$ rosrun --debug beginner_tutorials talker.py

[rosrun] Looking in catkin libexec dirs: /home/pi/catkin_ws/devel/share/beginner_tutorials

[rosrun] Looking in rospack dir: /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials

[rosrun] Searching for talker.py with permissions /111

[rosrun] Running  /home/pi/catkin_ws/src/beginner_tutorials/scripts/talker.py`

Not more output. After 1 sec or less, I return to the prompt. Nothing in rqt_console.

Could anyone help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300366/%5Bsolved%5D-rosrun-beginner_tutorials-talker.py-has-no-effect/) by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2018-08-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-08-12**:
Two questions:

1 - after catkin_make did you source the setup file("source devel/setup.bash")?

2 - Did you restart roscore after catkin_make?

**Comment by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on 2018-08-12**:
Thanks for questions.

1. Not before your question. Yes now. Without more result.
2. Yes.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2018-08-12**:
Did you try "rostopic list" to see if the talker is talking?

**Comment by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on 2018-08-13**:
Thanks. If I start listener.py, I have:

```
$ rostopic list
/chatter
/rosout
/rosout_agg
```

Good. Next step :

```
$ rostopic type /chatter 
std_msgs/String
$ rostopic hz /chatter 
subscribed to [/chatter]
no new messages
no new messages
..
```

**Comment by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) on 2018-08-13**:
If I run only talker.py and not listener.py, I have:

```
$ rostopic list -v

Published topics:
 * /rosout_agg [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 publisher

Subscribed topics:
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log] 1 subscriber
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have found the issue.

It was a problem of indentation in the script talker.py (the conditional part of script was put in the def part.)

Thanks to the helpers.

---

Originally posted by [loic](https://answers.ros.org/users/36958/loic/) with karma: 18 on 2018-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0